# DotNet Runtime Docker-Image says it needs SDK

Tags: docker, arm, .net-core

I'm trying to run a Docker container created from the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/runtime:3.1-buster-slim-arm32v7 AS runner
WORKDIR /app

COPY MyApp/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1 ./
COPY SomeFolder SomeOtherFolder

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MyApp.dll"]
```

However, I get the following error message:

`It was not possible to find any installed .Net Core SDKs. Did you mean to run .NET Core SDK commands? Install a .NET Core SDK from: https://aka.ms/dotnet-download`

When I open a console within the container, I can execute `dotnet MyApp.dll` without any problems, and earlier versions of the image also worked. Replacing `ENTRYPOINT` with `CMD` also doesn't help.

Comment: So have you installed the required version of .NET Core?  The requirements of earlier versions might have been different.  The Docker Runtime now requires .NET Core.  **Be sure you install the version that is required.**

Comment: @Ramhound I am using the .NET Core image, so why would I need to install .NET Core myself? And as the question says, the application works fine when I start it manually.